# T-SQL: Check if date is in proper format within Where-Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, where-clause

How is it possible to check within the where-clause, if the date parameter is set and if it's in the proper format (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

Here is my `SP` with parameter `@birthdaysearch` in format (`dd/mm/yyyy`):

```
Select *
From Clients as c
WHERE
    CASE ISDATE(@birthdaysearch)
        WHEN 0 THEN (c.BirthDay LIKE '%')
        WHEN 1 THEN (c.BirthDay LIKE CONVERT(datetime,@birthdaysearch,103))
    END
```

Why isn't that working?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do in your where clause?  What datatype is the BirthDay column?

Comment: the @birthdaysearch parameter is an optional searchfield for the users, if someone is trying to filter the data by birthdate. And the format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS".

Comment: And the datatype of BirthDay?  If optional, will the @birthdaysearch parameter be null?

Comment: As I said, the BirthDay column is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'. Yes it can happen that the parameter is null.

Comment: So the BirthDay column is a varchar?

Comment: You will make this much more performant if both your column type and the parameter type were of `datetime` type.  Not sure why your birthday column would need birthday down to the second either...

Comment: Ah.  Ok.  If it's a datetime, it doesn't have a format - it only has a format when output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax:

```
Select *
From Clients as c
WHERE ISDATE(@birthdaysearch) = 0 OR 
      (ISDATE(@birthdaysearch) = 1 AND c.BirthDay LIKE CONVERT(datetime, @birthdaysearch, 103))
```

or:

```
Select *
From Clients as c
WHERE c.BirthDay LIKE CASE WHEN ISDATE(@birthdaysearch) = 0 THEN '%'                   
                           ELSE CONVERT(datetime, @birthdaysearch, 103) END
```

But it is very strange why are you comparing dates with `LIKE`?
I suggest you the following:

```
Select *
From Clients as c
WHERE c.BirthDay = CASE ISDATE(@birthdaysearch) WHEN 0 THEN c.BirthDay
                    ELSE CAST(@birthdaysearch AS DATE) END
```

Comment: The last one gives me the follwing error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Answer (score -1):

Given the conversation in the comments, I think the following would be appropriate:

```
Select *
From Clients as c
WHERE COALESCE(@BirthDaySearch, c.BirthDay) = c.BirthDay
```

So, given that your parameter is a datetime type, and is nullable, there is no need to check the date format, as it will always be valid (or null) when it hits the sproc.

Comment: `Msg 174, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).`